# PDF Annotation not visible on Image using pdfbox API

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have text annotation on my pdf but when I am converting pdf to image file using pdfbox api, annotation disappears(not visible on image). I have searched for couple of forums but I did not get accurate answer of this question.

```
for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
    BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page,70,ImageType.RGB);

    // suffix in filename will be used as the file format
    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pdfFullPath + "-" + (page+1) + ".png", 70);
}
```

Creating Text annotation like below

```
//generate instanse for annotation
PDAnnotationTextMarkup txtMark = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_FREETEXT);
```

Some of the forums, I have read that one need to set Appearance to above object. But how I need to set appearance object to make annotation visible on my image.

Any help is greatly appriciated

Comment: You didn't attach a PDF, nor is the annotation code complete. Assuming that there is more code and that the PDF displays properly in Adobe Reader, then the cause is most likely that we don't support appearance generation for most annotation types. This is a known problem, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2019 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3353 .

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct, annotation is visible on acrobat reader but not on image. I had not attached any pdf because problem is generic and not ties to any specific pdf. Thanks for sharing info.

Comment: Since 2.0.16 the appearance stream of many annotations is now supported.